# Println is inserting an extra line that I don't want, "2 line breaks instead of 1"

Tags: java

After I have updated the record, the old file will be deleted and a new file will be created. Problem is, when my PrintWriter prints a record into the new file, an extra line will be created therefore leaving spaces between records. I am definitely missing something and maybe my logic is the problem here. I have already figuring it out for about an hour and still I can't come up with a solution.

```
public boolean updatecus() throws IOException
{
    boolean updated = false;
    String dbname = ""; String dbcon=""; String dbem="";
    String dbcid="";String dbcod="";String dbf="";
    String dbrid="";String dbic="";String dbstr="";
    String newstr="";
    
    File F = new File("Customer.txt");
    File Ftc = new File("Temp.txt");
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Ftc, true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
    Scanner Sc = new Scanner(F);
    Sc.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
    try
    {
        while(Sc.hasNext())
        {
            dbname = Sc.next();
            dbcid = Sc.next();
            dbcod = Sc.next();
            dbf = Sc.next();
            dbrid = Sc.next();
            dbic = Sc.next();
            dbcon = Sc.next();
            dbem = Sc.next();
            dbstr = dbname+","+dbcid+","+dbcod+","+dbf+","+dbrid+","+dbic+","+dbcon+","+dbem;
            newstr = this.Name+","+this.CheckInDate+","+this.CheckOutDate+","+this.Floor+","+this.RoomID+","+this.ICNumber+","+this.Contact+","+this.Email;
            if(dbname.equals(this.Name))
            {
                pw.println(newstr);
                updated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pw.println(dbstr);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Sc.close();
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
        F.delete();
        File dump = new File("Customer.txt");
        Ftc.renameTo(dump);  
    }
    return updated;
}
```

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println`? Print**ln** means print **l**i**n**e.

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase so they don't get confused with class names, which starts in uppercase.

Comment: Windows? `\r\n` issue?

Comment: @dan1st No, print will not work because when PrintWriter is printing the second record no new line will be generated, and that will cause several different records to be concatenated into 1 long record in the new textfile. But still thank you for helping.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes I am using windows, and no I don't think it's a \r\n issue, because i have already tried doing that manually with print to manually print a new line, the result is the same which is creating an extra new line that I don't want.

Comment: You mean there are teo line breaks instead of one? Use `print()` with a `\n` at the end.

Comment: @dan1st Yes exactly! 2 line breaks instead of 1, and ok I'll try your solution.

Comment: The problem is that println adds \r\n on windows which are seperate two line breaks. Windows should interpret both as one, however.

Comment: @dan1st It's working now! Thank you very much for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace println with print.

println will print values with new line each time you use it.

```
pw.print(newstr);
pw.print(dbstr);
```